# Examined Rows on mysql-table

Tags: mysql

In the last days, if got a problem on a table in a 5.0.95 - mysql-database.

The INNO-DB-table contains some entries, maybe 1000.
During the day a lot of elements are entered and deleted.
Normally the selects are really fast, due to the set indices.

But after some days the query slows down extremly.
When I let examine the select-statements the result says that the index is used and a huge number of elements has to be examined: ~80-100.000

Has anyone any suggestion, why this happens.

Comment: Have you tried using:  OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename to rebuild the table?

Comment: try using optimize table - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html. They suggest that it should be used when there are substanial inserts/deletes in an INNODB table.

Comment: I tried Optize table and afterwards the increasing numbers start again. So it helped just for a short period. The weird thing is, i didn't have to do it the 4 years before. Now it just needs days to "go down".